# How to structure dynamic javascript creation in Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, templates, flask, jinja2

I'm building a website using the (excellent) Python [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) in which there is a `templates/` folder and a `static/` folder. As the names suggest, the templates folder contains the templates which are rendered through the [jinja2 templating engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) and the static folder contains static content such as css, images, and static javascript files.

The javascript files is what I'm having trouble with though. Sometimes I want to place a jinja variable in a piece of js like this for example:

```
var requestJson = {'text': messageText, 'toUserId': {{ user.id }}};
```

If I do this in a do this in a `.js` file in the `static/` folder though, it isn't rendered, so this only works if I place it between `<script>` tags in the template file. That works, but it feels kinda messy because I now have some js in the static folder, and some js in the template files.

I could of course solve this by defining a `document.toUserId = {{ user.id }};` in the template and using that in the .js files, but yeah, that also feels kinda like a hack.

So my question is; what is the best/pythonic/neatest way of handling the insertion of dynamic values from jinja in javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very interesting question which I've thought about a lot at a certain point in time. By now I've done it and have seen it done precisely this way and it seems to me the best and most pythonic option. I think I can recall it's even recommended by Flask documentation (can't remember where).

Just put the specific variables that need a template rendering in a script in your `.html` files, using appropriate namespaces.

And all the rest in your `.js` files (I happen to be using CoffeeScript so it's even more important for me to put the least code possible in `<script>` tags directly in the template, for consistency reasons).

For instance, here is a (slightly modified) script that lies at the end of a template I'm currently working with:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    window.my_namespace.view_dashboard_vars = {};
    window.my_namespace.view_dashboard_vars.change_widgets_positions_url = "{{ url_for('dashboard.change_widgets_order', _external=True) }}";
    window.my_namespace.view_dashboard_vars.deactivate_widget_url = "{{ url_for('dashboard.deactivate_widget', _external=True) }}";
    window.my_namespace.view_dashboard_vars.dashboard_url = "{{ url_for('dashboard.view_dashboard', dashboard_id=dashboard.id, _external=True) }}";
    window.my_namespace.view_dashboard_vars.dashboard_id = "{{ dashboard.id }}";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select#dashboard_dates_presets").val("{{ preset }}");
        my_namespace.update_dashboard_dates_interval();
    });
  });
</script>
```

It works really well and after several projects and some of them being around for quite a bit by now, with lots of people involved, I can tell it's perfectly readable and maintainable. Just be careful to choose your namespaces wisely.

Comment: For an added bonus use `requirejs` or `browserify` to provide the dependency to your code, rather than a global variable (you'll still need to put the declaration of the package in your template) - then in your code you just `var pageConfig = require('pageConfig')` in your consuming code and access the variables you need.